# I want to create ,multidimensional array in swift with multiple inner arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create ,`multidimensional array` in **swift** with `multiple inner arrays`. I want the structure look like this but getting `error` while creating this. Please guide me how can I create this structure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
 var data2:[String] = []

    var LocationPickerData = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue"]
    var LocationPickerData2 = ["Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]
    var LocationPickerData3 = ["Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

    var Title = ["twwwitle1","sdfsaf","Prsdfasovosdfasflone","sfsa","sdfsf Blue"]
    var Title2 = ["seeefdasf Cheddar","sdfsf Jack","fsaf","Gouda","fasf Cheese", "sdfsf"]
    var Title3 = ["ddddsdfs ff", "fasfsdffasf"]



    var Name = ["fsdfa","fasfsafsf","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue"]
    var Name2 = ["afsadff Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]
    var Name3 = ["fffffff ffff", "jjjjjjj"]


var data2 = [
                    location[

                            location1[ LocationPickerData ],
                            location2[ LocationPickerData2],
                            location3[ LocationPickerData3]
                            ],
       titles[

                           title1[Title],
                           title2[Title2],
                           title3[Title3]
                        ],


                   names[

                          name1[Name],
                          name2[Name2],
                          name3[Name3]
                        ]
             ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your multidimensional array like this:

```
var data2 = [ 
              [
                LocationPickerData
                LocationPickerData2,
                LocationPickerData3,
              ], 
              [
                Title
                Title2,
                Title3,
              ], 
              [
                Name
                Name2,
                Name3,
              ]
            ]
```

Or you can declare a dictionary:

```
var data2 = [ 
              "Locations": [
                LocationPickerData
                LocationPickerData2,
                LocationPickerData3,
              ], 
              "Titles": [
                Title
                Title2,
                Title3,
              ], 
              "Names": [
                Name
                Name2,
                Name3,
              ]
            ]
```